# C#. Объясните смысл преобразования данных

Tags: c#

Объясните пожалуйста как работает ключевое checked в данном примере, в 1-ом просто выйдет 0 в консоли из-за переполнения, во втором же программа и вовсе не запустится. Но понять логику почему в первом примере она запускается, а во втором происходит System.OverflowException не могу.

1)

```
byte x = byte.MaxValue;
byte z = (byte) checked(x + 1);
Console.WriteLine(z);
```

2)

```
byte x = byte.MaxValue;
byte z = checked((byte) (x + 1));
Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Comment: Во втором случае вы пытаетесь преобразовать с лишком большое число. Более полно с примерами https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вас обманул оператор '+' который возвращет int, в данном случае. В следствии чего в первом варианте вы просто не верно используете оператор checked.

Разберем эту строку

```
1. byte z = (byte) checked(x + 1);
```

Вот какую последовательность выполнит компилятор.

```
2. int tempVariable = checked(x + 1);
3. byte z = (byte) tempVariable
```

В строке 2. нету переполнения так как результатом будет int. В строке 3. вполне легальный кастинг к byte

Почему же 'x + 1' возвращает int? Если коротко то он просто так работает. Этот оператор перегружен для int и нету для byte. Потому даже такой код будет вам говорить об ошибке:

```
    byte a = 2;
    byte b = 1;
    byte c = a + c;
```

И требовать что бы 'c' было int.

Answer (score 0):

Ключевое слово **checked** используется для явного включения проверки переполнения при выполнении арифметических операций и преобразований с данными целого типа.
То есть во время выполнения вашего кода будет создано исключение.

Источник: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked